# Save excel file from internet

Tags: java, excel, encoding, selenium, utf-8

I am trying to download Excel file from site using Selenium.

The way I'm doing it:

```
    WebElement excelList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("..."));

    excelList.click();

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:/load.xls");

    for (int i = 0; i < pageSource.length(); i++) {
        char c = pageSource.charAt(i);


        fos.write((byte) c);
    }

    fos.close();
```

The page source string length is equal to the file size that I downloaded manually from this site.

The problem is that I'm saving data incorrectly and MS Excel cannot open the saved file.

How can I save the file properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

All I need was to get input stream right from last page after clicking on load file button.
But method for getting page object 'lastPage()' has protected access.

Here is the way:

```
 private static void saveExcelFile(HtmlUnitDriver driver)  {
    Method m = driver.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("lastPage", null);
    m.setAccessible(true);
    Object obj = m.invoke(driver, null);

    Page page = (Page) obj;

    InputStream stream = page.getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("d:/load.xls");

    int c;

    while ((c = stream.read()) != -1) {
        fos.write(c);
    }

    fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `String.getBytes()` to sort of re-encode the characters back to a byte stream, but that probably still wont work.

Basically in order to hold the binary data of your excel file in a string the data has to be decoded using a character set. Because excel files aren't supposed to be read as plain text there are probably a lot of byte sequences that aren't valid character encodings. These byte sequences when decoded to `String` will probably just be represented as '?' (although this depends on the `Charset` that's actually getting used). When you try to re-encode the characters using `String.getBytes()` or any other method those '?' characters aren't going to get converted back to their original bytes but rather will be converted to the encoding for the unicode question mark character which is almost certainly not valid for the excel file format.

The real question is, why do you need to download this file through Se? Se is about testing how a browser renders web pages. If you need the Excel file why not just grab the href from the link you're clicking with Se and then use a simple `HttpUrlConnection` to download the file using a standard binary `InputStream`?

Comment: Well, the excel file is generated by executing java script and I just don't know precise link to the end url. The solution I am developing is intended to walk on sites and gather the data, and sometimes to download file. It seems to be easier just get data the way Selenuim allows